# Wordpress pagination returns the same posts

Tags: wp-query, pages, query-posts, page-template

I did search the other posts here related to this problem, and tried all of them in my case, but I can't seem to make it work (probably because I don't know enough code)

Can you please help me with the code below, as it stopped working lately with the latest Wordpress updates. I am using it in a page whish is set as the hompeage, but it shows the same posts on all the pages. I tried adding **page-navi** instead of my query, but it's not solving the problem.
I also tried this code but no result:

```
   <?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'paged'          => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
```

This is my query:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content col-md-9" role="main">
            <?php

            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array('post_type' => 'post','paged' => $paged);
            query_posts($args); 

            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'post-format/content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile;
            else:
                get_template_part( 'post-format/content', 'none' );
            endif;

            ?>
           <?php                                 
            $page_numb = max( 1, get_query_var('paged') );
            $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            echo moview_pagination( $page_numb, $max_page ); 
            ?>
        </div>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: there's no code for the `moview_pagination` function in your question, I also notice you're using `query_posts` which is a huge no no, replace it with the first code instead, `query_posts` is very very bad for lots of reasons. Is this in an AJAX request? What are you trying to do? Is there a reason you created a new query instead of modifying the main query via `pre_get_posts`? If you just wanted to change the number of posts shown that's trivial to do with a filter, or even via the settings page

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I really don't know. this is an older theme and it had this code. I simply want to show the posts (which works) with pagination, but fix the pagination problem which the code now has

Comment: are you trying to add a list of posts to an existing page? Create a new page? It's not clear what your goal was, or where this code is located in your theme, just that it involves a list of posts with broken pagination. We need more information!

Comment: sorry. yes, to an existing page. simply list the latest 20 posts on a page and have pagination (this code is placed on a page-2330.php). the code can be completely changed, I just need this part   get_template_part( 'post-format/content', get_post_format() );

Comment: I see, well in that case you can't use `get_query_var('paged')`  to get the current page, you will need to add a parameter to the URL for the page you're on, modify the pagination function to use that instead, and then read that parameter into your custom query.

Comment: thanks, but since I'm a novice, telling me what to do won't help, unfortunately. changing the code would

Comment: This is a programming stack, if you don't know basic PHP fundamentals then you won't understand the answer and you'll struggle to implement it. I'm not going to give you copy pasta, and I wouldn't be able to even if i wanted because you only shared partial snippets of the code, this isn't a case of change the Q's code and the problem is fixed, it isn't enough. This means any answer with code you get would need to be modified/adapted to be used on your specific site and could never be a drop in replacement. I've already helped you by describing the problem and fix, I can't write it for you

Comment: Also, if you are really looking for someone to just do the work for you for free, there's still no code shared for the `moview_pagination` function, so nobody will know how to modify it or how to build a replacement that works the same way

Answer (score 0):

You must change

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

To the following :

```
 $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

There is a difference in `page` and `paged` for a static front page, You may find your Answer here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters

Keep Posted

Comment: I actually tried that, but it doesn't change anything in my case. thanks anyway